# How can I used an android emulator against an exsisting phonegap app?

Tags: cordova

I have a phonegap test app. I can open the index.html in my browser. How can I use an android emulator to test this app? Do I do this in/from Eclipse?

Comment: if you use phonegap cli, just run `phonegap run android`, it will build the app and then if no device is detected it will try to start the emulator.

Comment: Thanks, that’s what I was looking for. Put that in an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use phonegap cli, just run phonegap run android, it will build the app and then if no device is detected it will try to start the emulator.